# Object configuration must be an array containing a "class" element in yii2 with mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Error > while login or signup using **yii2+ mongodb** gives an error.

MongoDB connection with yii2 is done. please help me to solve this problem.

main-local.php

```
return [
    'components' => [
            'mongodb' => [
            'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mongodb://sameer:27017/demo',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
             'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

main.php

```
return [
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
                'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
                'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: Difficult to solve the problem without seeing the code that reproduces the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please explain more what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please, specify correct error message. The message "Error > while login or signup using yii2+ mongodb gives an error." looks incorrect. At least I do not see that among all possible messages. Check the log in the yii2 debug pannel.

Comment: Related: [yii2 with mongodb not working for login or signup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45504082/2313887) which is basically asking the same question with the same error. Not sure if the posted answer there addresses the issue, but I left a comment on that question linking to this question and I'm doing the same here as any solution will likely be related.

Answer (score 0):

Check your vendor\yiisoft\extension.php 
I had the same error after I had installed one package which add uncorrect config array to the file vendor\yiisoft\extension.php

```
'tigrov/yii2-country' =>
     array (
        'name' => 'tigrov/yii2-country',
        'version' => '9999999-dev',
        'alias' =>
         array (
           '@tigrov/country' => $vendorDir . '/tigrov/yii2-country/src',
         ),
        'bootstrap' => 'tigrov\\country\\Bootstrap',
     ),
```

I've changed the previous one to the next one (just wrapped bootstrap in array)

```
'tigrov/yii2-country' =>
     array (
        'name' => 'tigrov/yii2-country',
        'version' => '9999999-dev',
        'alias' =>
         array (
            '@tigrov/country' => $vendorDir . '/tigrov/yii2-country/src',
         ),
         array(
            'bootstrap' => 'tigrov\\country\\Bootstrap',
         )
     ),
```