# yii2 with mongodb not working for login or signup

Tags: mongodb, yii2

we follow this youtube link to create yii2+mongodb connection but not working. check this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1msu95ZkRe8

gives an error **Object configuration must be an array containing a "class" element.**

in video user.php model  copy paste from doc file what is that file please help me.

Comment: This exact same question was asked a few hours earlier. Possibly a release error? Ref: [Object configuration must be an array containing a “class” element in yii2 with mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45500828/2313887)

Answer (score 0):

I successfully realized the login service at my own project using MongoDB. But I didn't use video tutorial you pointed out.

It looks like you have an error in your configuration file. I would first check the config for mongodb component. It must be something like following (`yii2-mongodb` project [README](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb))

```php
return [
    //....
    'components' => [
        'mongodb' => [
            'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mongodb://developer:password@localhost:27017/mydatabase',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Other component is worth checking out is the user component:

```php
return [
    //....
    'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'frontend\models\User', // This is your class with IdentityInterface
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
    ],
];
```

But in fact, similar error may appear for any configuration element of YII2.

Comment: Object configuration must be an array containing a "class" element in yii2 with mongodb.

Comment: on submit of signup form so please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Provide your source to discuss. Normally major of such errors appear due to mistypes. Check if your `class` option is written correctly.

Comment: will send you the files but witch files you want to check

Answer (score 0):

as per video change below function `behaviors` in `comman/models/User.php`

```
 public function behaviors()
{
  return [
    'timestamp' => [
     'class' => 'yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior',
    'attributes' => [
      ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
      ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at'],
        ]
    ]
  ];
}
```