# Yii2 mongodb error Object configuration must be an array containing a "class" element

Tags: mongodb, yii2

When I try to login OR Signup it does not work. If I try to login with wrong credential it works. But if I use right credential it gives error:

> Object configuration must be an array containing a "class" element.

Error on line:

```
 static::findOne(['username' => $username, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
```

and related line

```
$models = $this->createModels($rows);
```

My config is as below

### main.php

```
return [
  'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
  'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
  ],
];
```

### main-local.php

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'mongodb' => [
            'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mongodb://mts:123456@localhost:27017/mangodb',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User', // This is your class with IdentityInterface
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: Related: [yii2 with mongodb not working for login or signup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45504082/2313887) and [Object configuration must be an array containing a “class” element in yii2 with mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45500828/2313887). Similar error messages within the last day. You should view those questions.

Comment: https://viblo.asia/p/yii2-with-mongodb-YAQrMJ5gR40E
i followed this tutorial but getting error as above

Comment: @gauravdaxini Configuration looks ok,  add related model and controller also.

Comment: change `enableAutoLogin` **true**  to **false**.

Comment: can you kindly add the full stack trace ?

Comment: and also there is no other code i your cofig files other than the mentioned above?

Comment: This is a good question, I have been having this problem also. Are U using Linux or Windows? Are u using plain LAMP, or XAMPP.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the ActiveRecord object you are using (the one in `static::findOne(...)`) is an instance of `yii\mongodb\ActiveRecord` and **not** `yii\db\ActiveRecord` because the latter uses standard `db` component I assume you have not got configured.